# Dependence of Error: Does it matter for data-driven models?

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, independence

Linear regression assumes that the errors of the response variable are independent of each other.

Lets assume that a data-driven model like a random forest or multi-layer perceptron is trained/formed with some data and the resulting error of the response variable is not independent with each other.

Does this matter in any way? What can be concluded from such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) assumes independent, identically distributed (i.i.d.) errors.  Generalized Least Squares (GLS) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares , only requires the errors to be Multivariate Normal, but with any covariance (correlation) matrix.

Any departure from i.i.d. matters.

If you have a good basis (I don't mean Linear Algebra basis) for the error correlation matrix, you can use it as input to GLS.

Comment: Who exactly is the credit to mankind and statistical knowledge who down voted this answer?